# JavaScript code when closing/logging out via browser

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    leaveSiteStart = new Date;
    function leftSite() {
        var leaveSiteEnd = (new Date - leaveSiteStart);
        var roundleaveSiteEnd = Math.round(leaveSiteEnd, 1);
        _gaq.push(['pageTrackerTime._trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', document.getElementById('Name').value]);
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = leftSite;
</script>
```

I have used this code to impalement the duration of a user spend on a page before closing the browser or left the page with logging out.

But it failed to catch the event ...any thing wrong with the code?

Comment: by the time you sent the request, the page is gone and the request is cancelled. try looking at the network tab of your debugger, you should see a "cancelled" status on that request. if so, that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Catching the user leaving is basically impossible in modern day browsers. Back when FF4 came out, they broke the way of using a timed while loop to pause the exit.

Answer (score 0):

Because `_gaq` is an asynchronous call, the browser won't wait until the call is completed, so try to do some synchronous call.

In [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can do sync task by setting async flag to false, check if there is same way to do that.